# Symfony on Vagrant form submit does nothing

Tags: apache, symfony, apache2, vagrant

I'm working on setting up centOS using vagrant. I have loaded my current git repo (a Symfony project) into vagrant and am able to pull up the login screen of my project. So Apache and PHP appear to be working fine. I can load any public pages and also make AJAX requests to specific HTTP endpoints and get a successful response.

The issue then arises when I try and login. The page just reloads instead of logging me in and doesn't display any error messages as to why it didn't. It's almost as if the POST isn't being sent to the form. I was able to see an ajax request successfully communicate with mysql so I know there is a connection established and Apache is able to make and respond to requests. The problem only seems to be when I have a form that POSTs from one page to another. I have checked all error logs (Apache and Symfony) and there is nothing regarding a failure.

Any ideas on what the issue could be?

Comment: Not enough information. Link to git repo? Can you show the routes? Can you show us the controller actions?

Comment: The web app was working prior to this whole vagrant switch so im assuming the problem is not code related

Comment: running `php app/check.php` returns no errors?

Comment: Yea I just ran app/check.php and no errors came up. All it said was to update my requirements file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There ended up being a problem with FOSUserBundle and by upgrading it and fixing the config parameters it started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a few times. Check if you are not having a redirection from http to https. For example if you make a POST on some url, then after redirection you end up with a GET request.

Comment: I went into my puphpet config file and changed the vhost port from 80 to 443. I used https when accessing my vhost and was still not able to login. This time it told me it could not find my login handler that my form is submitting to.

Comment: I would say to make a request via curl in command line, and see what you get back, without using a browser. I still believe it has something to do with redirection. And try to remove https for now (you can add it later, after you solve the issue).